# update one column from COUNT(*) in another table depending on date in a third column

Tags: sql-server

I have an insert query that I would like to redo to an update query 
the database that I wish to update looks like:

```
Date (date, Null)
Hour (int, Null)
No of Alarms Stockholm (int, Null)
No of Alarms Sverige (int, Null)
```

My insert query that works looks like:

```
INSERT INTO [LABLOG].dbo.[AlarmStatistic] (
    [Date]
    ,[Hour]
    ,[No of Alarms Sverige]
    )
SELECT CAST([Event Date] AS DATE) AS [DATE]
    ,DATEPART(hour, [Event Date]) AS [Hour]
    ,COUNT(*) AS [No of Alarms Sverige]
FROM MYSERVER01.[SESVELOG].[dbo].[STATISTIC]
WHERE [Event Date] >= '2014-07-01'
    AND [Event Date] < '2014-12-01'
    AND [event text] LIKE 'Alarm.BSI Point - Alarm type: On; Alarm status: Normal; Event operator:%RAPID%; Presentation group:%'
GROUP BY CAST([Event Date] AS DATE)
    ,DATEPART(hour, [Event Date])
```

After reading several forum posts I came up with the following

```
UPDATE [LABLOG].[dbo].[AlarmStatistic]
SET [No of Alarms Sverige] = (
        SELECT CAST([Event Date] AS DATE) AS [DATE]
            ,DATEPART(hour, [Event Date]) AS [Hour]
            ,COUNT(*) AS [No of Alarms Sverige]
        FROM MYSERVER01.[SESVELOG].[dbo].[STATISTIC]
        WHERE [Event Date] >= '2014-07-01'
            AND [Event Date] < '2014-12-01'
            AND [event text] LIKE 'Alarm.BSI Point - Alarm type: On; Alarm status: Normal; Event operator:%RAPID%; Presentation group:%'
        GROUP BY CAST([Event Date] AS DATE)
            ,DATEPART(hour, [Event Date])
        )
```

This doesn't work though, I get

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

What I'm trying to do is a row count in one server depending on the text in one column and presenting the rows count by hour in the new table.

Comment: That formatting though... Wow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning value for `[No of Alarms Sverige]` using subquery. Your subquery should return only one value. But actually your subquery returns:

- Many rows (in the general case)
- Many columns (in all cases)

I think that following query should help:

```
UPDATE [LABLOG].[dbo].[AlarmStatistic]
SET [No of Alarms Sverige] = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS [No of Alarms Sverige]
        FROM MYSERVER01.[SESVELOG].[dbo].[STATISTIC]
        WHERE [Event Date] >= '2014-07-01'
            AND [Event Date] < '2014-12-01'
            AND [event text] LIKE 'Alarm.BSI Point - Alarm type: On; Alarm status: Normal; Event operator:%RAPID%; Presentation group:%'
            AND CAST([Event Date] AS DATE) = [Date]
            AND DATEPART(hour, [Event Date]) = [Hour]
        )
```

Comment: Thank you oryol
It works like a charm, I now only have to learn how and why "s" and "s." works in the query

Comment: It's table alias. But actually it can be removed in this case. I've updated my answer